# How to test if a sheet exists in Google Sheets by formulas

Tags: google-sheets

Which is the best way to test if a sheet exists or not in a Google spreadsheet, only using formulas (by a script it is easy, but I need speed!)?

For example, using `=error.type('mysheet'!A1)` gives error 4, but I am looking for something more specific... (error 4 could mean also something else...)

Many thanks

Answer (score 8):

I'm using `=IF(ISREF('Nov 17'!BT39), 'Oct 17'!BT39, "")` to determine if a sheet exist. Maybe that will help.

> Checks whether a value is a valid cell
>   reference.

My sheet **time recording** has the cell F5 (="October 2017").

Maybe you need to build your sheet name from a string. If so, use INDIRECT to build the sheet path. `=IF(ISREF(INDIRECT("'" & LEFT(F5, 3) & " ''" & Right(F5, 2) & "'" & "!BT39")), TRUE, FALSE)`

That gives me that path to **Oct '17**, my reference sheet, which I want to check if exist or not.

Greetings